# serverless-s3-local plugin and @aws-sdk/client-s3 returns an error with PutObjectCommand

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, serverless-framework

What I'm trying to do it's to save a file csv with a fake s3 (with serverless-s3-local plugin), but for some reason, the endpoint is giving an error. I followed these instructions [serverless-s3-local](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-s3-local) but with library "@aws-sdk/client-s3".

Note: I run the command described in the documentation `aws --endpoint http://localhost:4569 s3 cp ~/tmp/data.csv s3://local-bucket/userdata.csv --profile s3local` and everything works well. So maybe the problem could be in the params or methods that I'm using, but I haven't could find the solution.

This is the following error that I'm getting:

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND local-bucket.localhost
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:71:26)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {   errno: -3008,   code: 'ENOTFOUND',   syscall: 'getaddrinfo',   hostname: 'local-bucket.localhost',   '$metadata': { attempts: 1, totalRetryDelay: 0 } }
```

These are some configurations that I have in the custom and resources sections in serverless.yml

```
custom:
  # S3
  s3:
    bucketName: local-bucket
    host: localhost
    directory: /tmp

resources:
  Resources:
    NewResource:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties:
        BucketName: ${self:custom.s3.bucketName}
```

And this is my temporal code:

```
  main.ts
  import { S3Manager } from "../../../../shared/utils/aws/s3Manager";

  private _contentTypeXlsx: string = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet';
  private _contentTypeCsv: string = 'text/csv;charset=utf-8';

  const s3Config= new S3Manager('S3RVER', 'S3RVER', 'us-east-1', 'local-bucket');
  let bucketKey
  let responseUpload
  const fileName = `ExportedFile.csv`;
  bucketKey = `ExportedFiles/${Date.now()}/${fileName}`;
  const fileCsv = await new ObjectsToCsv(arrivals);
  responseUpload = await s3Manager.uploadFiles({  Key: bucketKey, Body: fileCsv.toString(), ContentType: this._contentTypeCsv });
```

---

```
s3Config.ts

import { S3Client, PutObjectCommand, GetObjectCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";
export class S3Manager {
    
        s3Client: any;
        awsS3: any
        bucketParams: any;
    
        constructor(keyId: string, accessKey: string, region: string, bucketName: string) {
            const configAwsClient = {
                s3ForcePathStyle: true,
                accessKeyId: keyId,
                secretAccessKey: accessKey,
                endpoint: 'http://localhost:4569',
            };
            this.s3Client = new S3Client(configAwsClient);
            this.bucketParams = {
                Bucket: bucketName
            }
        }
    
        async uploadFiles(filters: {}): Promise<any> {
            let success = true;
            try {
                var params = {
                    ...this.bucketParams,
                    ...filters
                };
                const command = await new PutObjectCommand(params);
                const response = await this.s3Client.send(command);
                console.info('Response of putObject', response);
            }
            catch (err) {
                success = false;
                console.log(err);
            }
            return success;
        } }
```

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution to this problem.
It was required to change the property s3ForcePathStyle instead forcePathStyle because of the v3 of aws-sdk.

```
    const configAwsClient = {
        forcePathStyle: true,
        credentials: {
            accessKeyId: keyId,
            secretAccessKey: accessKey,
        },
        endpoint: 'http://localhost:4569',
    };
```

If you want to see more details about this problem, the solution was resolved here: https://github.com/ar90n/serverless-s3-local/issues/492